Flicker when using i3 on top of Ubuntu with GTK app
When using GTK app, I have some heavy screen flickering. This does not happen for:

the same app but build with QT (e.g., Transmission QT is fine while Transmission GTK is broken).
when not using i3 but the stock Ubuntu window manager.


Any help would be welcome.
With i3, running GTK_DEBUG=geometry transmission-gt gives
libEGL warning: failed to get driver name for fd -1

libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information

libEGL warning: failed to get driver name for fd -1

It seems that when the flickering is occuring, GDB_DEBUG prints
[0x55cee28f2970] GtkScrollbar   width for height: -1 is minimum 6 and natural: 6 (hit cache: yes)
[0x55cee28ef880] GtkScrollbar   height for width: -1 is minimum 6 and natural: 6 (hit cache: yes)

Debug info:
lsb-release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

sudo lshw -c video           
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:198 memory:603c000000-603cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

lspci -v 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P 6p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2315
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 198
    Memory at 603c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 181
    Memory at 603d180000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal_pci
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci

00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: bc200000-bc2fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=20, subordinate=49, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 3000-3fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: b0000000-bc1fffff [size=194M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 6000000000-601bffffff [size=448M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=50, subordinate=79, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 4000-4fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: a2000000-ae1fffff [size=194M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 6020000000-603bffffff [size=448M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module
    Subsystem: Lenovo GNA Scoring Accelerator module
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 603d1e2000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 603d1c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_vsec
    Kernel modules: intel_vsec

00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141
    Memory at 603d1b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 603d140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 603d1e1000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 603d100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 603d1e0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 142
    Memory at 603d1a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 603d1d8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at 603d1df000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 603d1d4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at 4017000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 180
    Memory at 603d1dd000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake AMT SOL Redirection (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake AMT SOL Redirection
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 2060 [size=8]
    Memory at bc301000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 199
    Memory at 603d1d0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 603d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 603d1dc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at a0800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci

04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 980 PRO
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at bc200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme


Any help would be welcome
